What is the difference between earlier and sooner in the contexts I have provided and in similar contexts? I still don't understand
For the sake of finally ending all this, please explain the difference between earlier and sooner in relation to my three sentences and don't provide me with any unsolicited only indirectly related information.
Person A gets a promotion in March and person B gets a promotion in May. Did Person A get a promotion 1 month earlier or sooner than Person B?
Their train left three minutes sooner or earlier than mine.
Newspaper A published the article a day sooner or earlier than Newspaper B.

The 'difference' is that earlier would be more idiomatic in all three cases, because specific time/date differences are mentioned.

If English is not your native language, I am 100% sure that a good hardback bilingual dictionary will do the job in addition to online things like Collins and Merriam Webster. And Kate is right, of course, early/late generally refer to time as on a clock. And for the last time, there is no Canadian/American English difference in any of your questions. The major difference is in law and spelling. I have mentioned this to you several times. And I do not understand why you keep asking about some supposed difference in regular contexts.

You say you do not understand the difference between the two but your tags says Canadian and American English and difference. What are we to make of this? If you bothered to pay me some heed as I told you I am a CI, you might learn something about interpretation and how it works. But that didn't seem to phase you.

@Lambie - it didn't seem to faze him or her either :-)

@MichaelHarvey Don't do that again please. Just  tell me. It's from fast typing and not rereading myself. I cannot stand having a dictionary quoted to/at me for baby s*** from a peer. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between earlier and sooner in these contexts?

If I had known you had asked that question earlier... which is 90%  identical... I would have saved myself the time and effort I put into answering this question.

Earlier is correct in all three examples, as "sooner" shouldn't be used to describe relative time in the past.
"Their train left sooner than mine" creates a conflict by using the past tense "left" and "sooner" -- if a non-native speaker said this to me, I would be relying on other cues to determine whether they had used the wrong verb tense or swapped 'earlier' for 'sooner'.
To use "sooner", you need to be in the present or future:

Newspaper A is publishing the article a day sooner than Newspaper B.
Person A will get a promotion a month sooner than person B.

Now, I actually still find the above somewhat awkward. Other native speakers may disagree, but I don't like the use of "sooner" when used alongside a specific time frame, e.g. "a month sooner". To me, you can specify a time frame alongside "earlier" or you can use it on its own, for example:

Their train left earlier than mine.
Person A got a promotion a month earlier than person B.

...however, "soon" is its own time frame and shouldn't be used alongside a specific time frame. Note that if someone said to me e.g. "a day sooner" their meaning would be perfectly clear and I might not even notice, however, these sentences sound much more natural to me:

Newspaper A is publishing the article sooner than Newspaper B.
Person A will get a promotion sooner than person B.

Last but not least, "soon" should describe a relatively short time period: "a month sooner" just doesn't sound right, as a month is a significant period of time. "A week sooner" sounds okay, but "two weeks sooner" might be pushing it.

You're my savior :-) Thank you:-) But would it be okay to use soon in reported speech, e.g. He said he would be here soon and what about wishes about the past e.g. I wish the government had acted sooner.?

@K945 new questions should be asked separately. You're the one who goes on about users going off track and talking about unrelated things instead of focusing on your question. For example, "Please, stick to my question and don't provide any additional information I haven't asked for even if it's somehow related because you always get so carried away that you never answer my question. I don't mean to be rude but I have observed this way too often …"

Both of those are fine, anyway. Please remember to accept or upvote answers you find helpful.

Earlier

As I said earlier…

You wouldn't use sooner here. The comparative form "earlier" tells us the action happened at some point in the past, before ‘now’.

Their train left three minutes earlier than mine.

Someone's train departed three minutes before the speaker's train.
If the speaker's train was scheduled to leave at 8.09AM, someone else's was leaving at 8.06AM. Their train left earlier than the speaker probably expected.

Their flight to New York left earlier than mine.

Bob got a promotion in late March while Carol got hers in late April.
Bob got promoted before Carol. Both promotions happened in the past.

Bob got his promotion a month earlier than Carol's


The Washington Post published their scoop before anyone else.
The scandal was first printed by The Washington Post.


The news was reported earlier (previously) by The Washington Post.
The Washington Post published their article a day earlier than The New York Times.
Newspaper A published the article earlier than newspaper B.

Soon

Soon is an adverb that means in a short while or time. The word has its origins from old English ‘sona’ meaning immediately.
    See you soon.
    She left the house as soon as the sun rose.
    We will be there soon.
Soon doesn’t talk about a particular time though. How soon? We don’t know! Soon has a sense of urgency that early doesn’t have. For example,
Can you send this document as soon as possible – we need it almost immediately.

Source: Grammar.com

soon
in or within a short time; before long; quickly:
Examples

We’ll soon be there.
How soon (= When) can we sign the contract?
"When would you like to meet?" "The sooner the better."
Source: Cambridge Dictionary


sooner
   1. Sooner or later  you'll get the hang of it
   2. The sooner you do your taxes the better.
   3. No sooner said than done
   4. no sooner ... than
   (No sooner had I watered the plants than it rained.)
These are fixed phrases but note the first three refer to the present or the future.  Despite the verbs "said" and "done" being in the past participle, the third idiom means you will do something immediately.

But what about the other sentences? Again, you came up with a bunch of other examples and ignored my other two. Also, if soon cannot be used with past tenses, how can it be used in reported speech (He said he would be here soon.) or in a sentence like I wish the government had acted sooner? Or would earleir be a better choice?

I talked about all three sentences: the promotion, the train and the newspaper. I did not ignore anything, I gave examples that were, in my opinion, more natural.

The Washington Post sentence isn't identical with mine because you have omitted the word than and didn't mention another newspaper.

@K945 I have included the newspaper sentence which is now identical to yours. I hope that satisfies your very exigent needs.

Thank you very much.
